# Transforming data in R into two separate rows in order to use friedman.test

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have data that is in format that looks like this:

`ID1 name1 R1 M1 R2 M2`

`ID2 name2 R1 M1 R2 M2`

But in order to use friedman.test function the data should be in format like this if i understood the docs correctly:

`ID1 name1 R1 M1`

`ID1 name1 R2 M2`

`ID2 name2 R1 M1`

`ID2 name2 R2 M2`

How can I transform the data in the correct format or what is the best way to use the function in this dataset?

Comment: checkout `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package

Comment: @Cettt I think this one should solve it! Thanks :)